# With VMware 5, how does memory pooling works across clusters

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-server, vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter

With new memory entitlement in vSphere 5, if I have 2 clusters configured with the same license level. Would my memory entitlement be calculated separately for each cluster, or will it pool everything together (managed by the same vCenter server)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pooled vRAM is per vCenter.